# Sequelize String being output as [Object object]

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

In my Sequelize models I have this model

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, Sequelize) {
return sequelize.define('TradingPlan', {
  id: {
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
  },
  name:Sequelize.STRING,
  symbol: Sequelize.STRING(10),
  symbol_pair: Sequelize.STRING(10),
  entry_type: Sequelize.STRING(10),
  conditional_long_entry_point: Sequelize.DECIMAL(18,8),
  conditional_short_entry_point: Sequelize.DECIMAL(18,8),
  entry_price: Sequelize.DECIMAL(18,8),
  entry_order_type: Sequelize.STRING(10),
  pyramid_entry: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
  exchange: Sequelize.STRING(30),
  notes: Sequelize.STRING,  <----------This is the problem one
```

When I retrieve the `notes` table data it outputs as

`[object Object]`

Then when I try to edit one of my posts in this table it will not accept it because it is an Object. Even though it is input as a String. I usually input `This is a good note!`

The error I receive is this

```
name: 'SequelizeValidationError',
errors:
 [ ValidationErrorItem {
   message: 'notes cannot be an array or an object',
   type: 'string violation',
   path: 'notes',
   value: [Object],
   origin: 'CORE',
   instance: [Object],
   validatorKey: 'not_a_string',
at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\node\trade- 
mentor\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:517:31
)
```

I haven't had any luck googling this, has anyone else seen this?

Comment: Provide your `notes` data example.

Comment: It is just a text area used for notes. I usually type `This is a good note!`

Comment: Where do you call update the TradingPlan?

Answer (score 0):

I had my datatype wrong in Mysql, I had it as `Blob`, I also changed my datatype in Sequelize to `Text` after doing more reading about it.